# Help with Get/Set Test Coverage

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have a class with the following code that isn't covered in the rest of the test:

```java
public Organization runningOrg {
     get {
          return [SELECT Id, IsSandbox FROM Organization LIMIT 1];
     }
     set;
}
```

Any help on how I would write a test to cover this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should fix this, as a getter with an SOQL that runs every time will eat up governor limits.

Instead:

```
public static Organization runningOrg { get; set; }
static {
  runningOrg = [SELECT IsSandbox FROM Organization];
}
```

As far as testing it, you'd just need one line of code.

```
Boolean isSandbox = Utils.runningOrg.IsSandbox;
```

Replace `Utils` with the name of the class that has this variable.

Normally, assertions are suggested, but in this case, there's no point, as you'd have to just run the query to get the value, which was the query you just ran.

Comment: Thanks. I need to do some work to be able to test the Apex code but it looks straightforward enough.

Answer (score 2):

sfdcfox offers the better approach (make it a static variable, because it's something that will not change).

In general though, the answer to "how do I get coverage for thing X?" is simply "you need to execute thing X as part of a unit test".

The other part to that is your test needs to do the appropriate setup to guarantee that you execute the code you want coverage for. That usually means:

- Inserting test records so that any queries you need to execute can retrieve at least one row
- Inserting any Custom Setting records that your code relies on
- Just generally setting fields and preparing helper classes so that they have the right data to get you into any if/else if/else blocks

In this particular case, there is no real setup that you need to do.

Assuming that a *property* (a class variable with a setter and/or a getter) would be the right approach for you (it isn't in your particular case), you'd test it by causing the setter or getter to run.

```java
// Non-static variables/properties need an instance of their class to be able to access
//   them
MyClass instance = new MyClass();

// Using regular 'ol dot notation to access a property makes an implicit call
//   to the getter, and would provide coverage for it if executed in a test method
Organization org = instance.runningOrg;
```

#### bonus

If you do need a class property (static or instance) instead of a simple variable, and it's something that's expensive to compute (like executing a query, since we only get 100 of those per synchronous transaction), then a common pattern to use is *lazy loading*.

Basically, only compute the value the first time that you actually need it and not a moment before, and then store it for subsequent uses (within a given transaction) so you don't re-compute it.

```java
public class MyClass{
    public String myLazyLoad {
        get{
            if(myLazyLoad == null){
                // This code is only run once, and only if the variable hasn't
                //   already been set
                myLazyLoad = 'expensive computation result';
            }

            return myLazyLoad;
        }
        set;
    }
}
```